# Ruby on rails. Ransack search on money-rails Monetize attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack, currency, money-rails

I am having problems searching a money-rails/Monetized attribute using ransack. I am only able to search in cents. I have a model (gig) with a money attribute `salary`. I can create this model no problem with:

```
 <%= form.input :salary %>
```

Which saves the value in a `salary_cents` column as expected as in my gig model I have:

```
monetize :salary_cents
```

I can then show the salary in the view with:

```
<%= @gig.salary %>
```

The problem I am having is with searching this field with ransack. The `salary` attribute is null, and the `salary_cents` attribute is populated as it should be, but this means I can only search in cents.

For the search I am using:

```
<%= f.search_field :salary_cents_gteq %>
<%= f.search_field :salary_cents_lteq %>
```

but to search `$30`, I would have to input `3000`. Is there any way of manipulating the inputted data, multiplying by 100,  before sending the search request?  Are there any easier ways that I am missing?

I have searched this and cannot find any information on searching Money fields with ransack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ransack's [custom predicates](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Custom-Predicates) saves the day!

```
# config/initializers/ransack.rb
Ransack.configure do |config|

    config.add_predicate 'gteq_euros', 
        arel_predicate: 'gteq',
        formatter: proc { |v| v * 100 },
        validator: proc { |v| v.present? }

    config.add_predicate 'lteq_euros', 
        arel_predicate: 'lteq',
        formatter: proc { |v| v * 100 },
        validator: proc { |v| v.present? }
end
```

once you restart your rails application you could ransack by dollars / euros as you wanted:

```
<%= f.search_field :salary_cents_gteq_euros %>
<%= f.search_field :salary_cents_lteq_euros %>
```